# VBA copy and paste macro != manual copy paste

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Im trying to copy and paste a table from excel into a word document.

I can do it manually - highlight the cell, CTRL+C, go to word, CTRL+V. it works fine.

But when I write a macro to do it the cells are twice the height, like the line height in each cell gets changed for some reason. why is it different? I recorded the manual procedure and it is the same function (PasteExcelTable) being called.

```
Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(wordDocPath)

With wordDoc
    ' cost report
    Dim wordRng As Word.Range
    Dim xlRng As Excel.Range
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim r As String

    'Copy the cost report from excel sheet
    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("COST REPORT")
    i = sheet.Range("A:A").Find("TOTAL PROJECT COST", Range("A1"), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext).row
    r = "A11:M" + Trim(Str(i))

    Set xlRng = sheet.Range(r)
    xlRng.Copy

    'Copy and Paste Cost report from Excel
    Set wordRng = .Bookmarks("CostReport").Range 'remember original range

    If .Bookmarks("CostReport").Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        .Bookmarks("CostReport").Range.Tables(1).Delete
    End If

    .Bookmarks("CostReport").Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    .Bookmarks.Add "CostReport", wordRng    'reset range to its original positions
End With
```

Comment: You might [check the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa202201%28v=office.10%29.aspx) and try using `true` for one of the last two arguments, see if that fixes it.

Comment: if I set the last one to true (RTF) it looks different, still doesn't look like a CTRL+V. but I got pretty close by updating the formatting in code after pasting it as HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
With wordDoc
    'Paste table from Excel
    Set wordRng = .Bookmarks(bookMarkName).range 'remember original range

    If .Bookmarks(bookMarkName).range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        .Bookmarks(bookMarkName).range.Tables(1).Delete
    End If

    .Bookmarks(bookMarkName).range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    .Bookmarks.Add bookMarkName, wordRng    'reset range to its original positions

    Dim paraFmt As ParagraphFormat
    Set paraFmt = .Bookmarks(bookMarkName).range.Tables(1).range.ParagraphFormat

    paraFmt.SpaceBefore = 0
    paraFmt.SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    paraFmt.SpaceAfter = 0
    paraFmt.SpaceAfterAuto = False
    paraFmt.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
    paraFmt.WidowControl = True
    paraFmt.KeepWithNext = False
    paraFmt.KeepTogether = False
    paraFmt.PageBreakBefore = False
    paraFmt.NoLineNumber = False
    paraFmt.Hyphenation = True
    paraFmt.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevelBodyText
    paraFmt.CharacterUnitLeftIndent = 0
    paraFmt.CharacterUnitRightIndent = 0
    paraFmt.CharacterUnitFirstLineIndent = 0
    paraFmt.LineUnitBefore = 0
    paraFmt.LineUnitAfter = 0
    paraFmt.MirrorIndents = False
    paraFmt.TextboxTightWrap = wdTightNone
    paraFmt.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft

    .Bookmarks(bookMarkName).range.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample piece of code for me please. I tested it From VBA Excel with different table types and it gave me satisfactory results. Please amend it whereever required... for example File Name / Sheet name etc...

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object
    Dim FlName As String

    FlName = "C:\MyDoc.doc"

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True

    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(FlName)

    With oWordDoc
        Dim xlRng As Range

        Set xlRng = Sheets(1).Range("A1:D10")
        xlRng.Copy

        .Bookmarks("CostReport").Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
        Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: nope, the table is still pasting in with double cell height, I was only able to solve this by re-formatting them manually in the macro

Comment: Please try this. Autofit the rows and columns in Excel and then try again :) You will have to first increase the columns and rows and then do the Autofit. Waiting to hear from you...

Comment: I tried autofit to window, autofit to contents, no change there. it is because of paragraph size in each cell. the paragraph settings "Spacing" is set to 6pt before and after, multiple at 1.15. it should be 0/0, single